# KeyEventDispatcher doesn't work

Tags: java, exception, keyevent

I want to use the keyboard to evoke certain reactions of the computer. So I wrote a KeyEventDispatcher but I get a NullPointerException. I cannot say in which line the exception occurs because the compiler refers in any case to the same line, no matter if there stands code or it doesn't. But the method seems to be called because it prints "test".

Here's the relevant code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;

public class Game extends JFrame
{
  private JFrame frame;

  public Game()
  {
    frame = new JFrame();
    KeyEventDispatcher keyEventDispatcher = new InputKeyListener();
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(keyEventDispatcher);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

private class InputKeyListener implements KeyEventDispatcher
{   
    private KeyEvent e;

    @Override 
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            System.out.println("test");                    
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            //do something                    
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_R){

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Spiel$InputKeyListener.dispatchKeyEvent(Spiel.java:43)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1020)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

EDIT: SOLVED - The problem wasn't the code but BlueJ, which I am forced to use by the teacher. I don't know why but it executed an old code although I recompiled often. I had to restart BlueJ to make it execute the new code. But thanks to everybody for helping me :)

Comment: It's interesting that your compiler refers to the same line no matter what's on it. Can you post your stacktrace anyway? And, can you confirm that you are actually recompiling and running the recompiled code?

Comment: Just tried your code and it works (after I added a `main`). You have to give some more details.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: I added the stack trace to the question and I can confirm.

Comment: @GabrielNegut: You mean a main method? I try it

Comment: Why have you created a instance variable `private KeyEvent e;` that is not used anywhere.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. May be the issue is some where else.

Comment: @Braj: I know it is not used and I originally didn't have it but I didn't know what else to try so I did this

Comment: The problem is not in this code. Its' inside `Spiel.java` class at line `Spiel.java:43`

Comment: I should have told that. The original name of this class is the German word Spiel but for StackOverflow I changed it to Game to make it more international :)